# Javascript match regex links

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have the following text in a div:

```
[http://www.google.com Google this link] some other random text [http://example.com and another website] but don't parse [this is not a link, leave me alone].
```

What I tried to do was to convert the links into normal html links. The Format is always like this, so it opens with a [ and then the url, followed by the link text and then a closing ]. But I only want to match links, *not all text in square brackets*.

I want to use the `.match()` function in javascript to do this task, but I wasn't able to figure out the regex expression (I only need the text parts that are links - the rest should be a simple split).

Any help would be apprechiated.

Comment: 1 - What have you tried? 2 - First, you say you only want to match the links, then you say you only need the text parts... Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why `.match` and not `.replace`?

```
string.replace(/\[(https?:\/\/[^\]\s]+)(?: ([^\]]*))?\]/g, "<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
```

Comment: wow... perfect. Someday, I need to get the hang of this... thank you!!

Comment: @mffap Yes, regexes are somewhat difficult but can do a great job. If the answer was useful, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark on the left.